# How to detect CSS inheritance source?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

So far, I can only tell if a property is inherited or not, but I need to know the source of inheritance, (for ex, which CSS file caused the final value ?) is this possible ?

Is there a handy tool for this ?

**EDIT**

Here is what I get in chrome Computed Style (show inheritance)
See the direction property, there is no info about its inheritance source
[image]

Comment: You can do this by using fire bug.check my update 2.

Comment: it could also mean there is no inheritance for this property, default value is applied to it.

Comment: You are correctly using "Computed Style" and Sudarshan is probably right saying that `direction` has a default value in your case. Can you provide an example you are testing this on?

Comment: Its h1 tag, Yes you are right Sudarshan, it seems that its the default value which is not populated by inheritance  .. what's the practical way to override direction for all the viewed page though ?

Comment: if you want to override any default property add it in `element.style {
}` at `styles panel`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this job very easily by using Firebug in Firefox or Chrome's Developer Tools.

### Chrome Developer Tools

Like image shows below.

[image]

For more information check [Chrome Developer Tools: Element Styles Here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles)

### In Firebug

Like image shows below.

[image]

For more information check [CSS Development Here](http://getfirebug.com/css)

You can install [Fire Bug From Here](http://getfirebug.com/)

### Update 1:

You can find it by just clicking `Show Inherited` check box on Chrome's `computed style` panel likes below.

[image]

### Update 2:

In Firebug, you just click inherited element what I showed below image.Then It will guide you to the relevant Inherited element's location.

**P.S.** - Same can do by using chrome Tool.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, although Firefox Fire Bug Tool is awesome, I couldn't find the property I am looking for listed, that is direction, but, its listed in chrome Computed Style

Comment: @SamirSabri check my update 1.Inside the chrome also you can do this.

Comment: @SamirSabri on chrome also you can do same thing just by clicking "Inherited From's Link".Same as firebug.It will direct you to relevant location.

Comment: Thanks Sampath for clarification, I found that what I see in the computed style is the default values which are not inherited ..

Answer (score 2):

The cascading nature of CSS makes the Styles browser in the [Elements Tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements) very useful, you can see the individual styles and where they come from, you can also see the final set of styles after it is computed and applied to the element.

[image]

#### EDIT

You can refer a property and its source from computed style panel

[image]

#### Reference

- [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements).

Comment: its hard to find it this way, I need to simply search for the property name to find it and find its inheritance source, this way you've shown above will force me look through all 'Inherited from' tabs to see if my property listed or not .. sadly there is no search option, its only available for the page html source

Comment: @SamirSabri: You can relate a property and its value using computed style panel no need to do a search operation, check my edit in answer

Comment: I've got your point, so, it seems that I am viewing the default value, which is not inherited .. please see discussion above